# Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen make status bar/notification bar visible for few seconds and then hides

Tags: android

I want to make full screen activity with no title bar and no status bar. I tried below mentioned code, it make activity full screen but status bar/notification bar is visible for few seconds and then hides. 
**Is there any way I can make activity full screen as soon as it appears to user.**

Code Tried: I tried it on android 2.3 and 4.1.2

1) Progrmatically:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

2) Or via AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Comment: Set it only in manifest.xml

Comment: i have a same problem when dialog open it hides staus bar and again it showns, i dont want to hide status bar? if you have answer please comment here

Answer (score 0):

Add the theme to your `<application>` tag in `manifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

Comment: I tried it in application tag , but it doesn't work. Same result as in activity tag.

Comment: Does doing this and removing it everywhere else work? *Only* have it in the application tag. Not in code, or in activity tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen** so please use **Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen** instead that as i mention below.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

It works for me, hope it help to you...:)

Comment: Tried using    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen". but not working.
One strange thing I noticed, even if I applied style to application, some activities show notification bar for few seconds and some not.

Comment: Then you can try this attribute under **application** tag.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Yes I tried under application tag also. But result is same, for some activities it work but for others it doesn't. I checked each activity tag carefully they all are using same attributes (name and label).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that by using `WindowManager` as you did but you just have to make change like;

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_semster_pdf);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Try to add the code as mentioned above or just check out at this link it will help you
 http://www.codespot.info/2017/11/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android-and.html